# Show DialogFragment in a Child Activity Android

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

In MainActivity.java, I extends TabActivity to use Tabhost.

`public class MainActivity extends TabActivity`

In each Tab, I use ActivityGroup to manage some child activity

`public class MerchandiserTabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup`

In a child activity A, I want to show DialogFragment. But it doesn't work.
Here is the error:

```
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@40570598 is not valid; is your activity running?
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:542)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:203)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:117)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:385)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1336)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:907)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
07-30 11:40:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think I have to show DialogFragment in it's parent activity. But it's convenient.
Are there any other solutions?

**EDIT**

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(view.getId()){
        ....
        case R.id.img_delete_all_photos:
            if(mTripSurveryImage.size() > 0){
                DialogFragment dialogFragment = new EAlertDialog(
                        new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                switch (which) {
                                case Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                    mTripSurveryImage.clear();
                                    imgNoPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    mViewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    break;
                                case Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                                }

                            }
                        }, "Warning!!!", mContext.getString(android.R.string.no),
                        mContext.getString(android.R.string.yes),
                        "Do you want to delete all the images?");

                dialogFragment.show(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
            }
            break;
}
```

This is my EAlertDialog:

```
public class EAlertDialog extends DialogFragment implements
        android.view.View.OnClickListener {
    public static final String TAG = "WaitingDialog";
    private String mTitle;
    private String mNegative;
    private String mPositive;
    private String mMessage;
    private OnClickListener mOnClickListener;

    public EAlertDialog(){

    }
    public EAlertDialog(OnClickListener listener, String title,
            String negative, String positive, String message) {
        mTitle = title;
        mNegative = negative;
        mPositive = positive;
        mMessage = message;
        mOnClickListener = listener;
        setCancelable(false);
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
    }

    // there is only negative button
    public EAlertDialog(OnClickListener listener, String title,
            String navigative, String message) {
        this(listener, title, navigative, null, message);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = null;
        if (mPositive == null) {
            layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_negative, null);
        } else {
            layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, null);
            layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_positive).setOnClickListener(this);
            ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_positive))
                    .setText(mPositive);
        }
        layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_negative).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_negative)).setText(mNegative);
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title)).setText(mTitle);
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.message)).setText(mMessage);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_negative:
            if (mOnClickListener != null) {
                mOnClickListener.onClick(getDialog(), Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            } else {
                dismiss();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btn_positive:
            if (mOnClickListener != null) {
                mOnClickListener.onClick(getDialog(), Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            } else {
                dismiss();
            }
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of doing this way is to reuse EAlertDialog.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: more code.............

Comment: are you in main thread

Answer (score 0):

use below code before showing dialog in your fragment if your using fragment i.e

```
if(!((Activity) context).isFinishing())
{
  dialog.show();
}
```

use below code before showing dialog in your activity if your using activity i.e

```
if!isFinishing())
{
  dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. My scenarios is display DialogFragment to alert when clicking Delete all photos Button.